# How do I categorize myself if I'm an owner of a corporation, and didn't make anything above my initial investment?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, limited-liability-company, s-corporation

I started an LLC which will be filing as an S-Corp.  Thus, my personal taxes are separate.  Am I self-employed, or employed by the LLC?  I also only received reimbursements for my investment.  Do I just report $0 income on my personal taxes?

Comment: What  details and clarity are needed so that OP can get it reopened.

Comment: I voted to repoen because I believe I can accurately answer this question without any more details. Though knowing this would be slightly helpful: Was the "reimbursement" paid as W2 wages, or as a distribution? Did the company have "income/profit" before "reimbursing" you?

Comment: I don't really see why this was closed TBH